# a href showing my site and then the url html

Tags: html, url

This is my code:

`<a href="www.rapidshare.com" target="_blank" class="link2">rapidshare</a`

The url I'm getting is http://mysite.com/www.rapidshare.com
Whats the problem?

Comment: Did you try making it http://www.rapidshare.com instead?

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix it with a protocol, because `www.rapidshare.com` is a valid filename:

```
<a href="http://www.rapidshare.com/" target="_blank" class="link2">rapidshare</a>
```

Always make sure to prefix your links with the proper protocol for external websites!

Comment: Just for user1104615's clarification, `www.rapidshare.com` will be viewed as a relative URL. Adding the complete path including protocol allows the browser to interpret it as an absolute URL. Reference: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="http://www.rapidshare.com" target="_blank" class="link2">rapidshare</a>
```

Comment: You might want to add the missing slash :P I can't do it without changing 5 more characters...

Answer (score 0):

Adding prefix `http://` should work.